# tkinter (ttk) leaving artifacts when updating widget

Tags: python, tkinter, ttk, ttkwidgets, tkinter-label

When updating a value in a widget using tkinter there's traces of the old widget's state on screen, and I was wondering if there's any fix to this. I'm assuming tkinter just re-draws whatever it needs to, not updating the old widget/old widget's state. Minimal reproducible example follows.

```py
from tkinter import *
from tkinter.ttk import *

window=Tk()
ttk.Style().configure("Info.TLabel",foreground="white", background="#1e2124",relief="sunken")

def update_label(currvar):
    current_var_levels = current_var.get()
    var_label=ttk.Label(window,text=f'{current_var_levels}'+'%',style="Info.TLabel")
    var_label.grid(row=0,column=1)

current_var=IntVar()
scale_bar = ttk.Scale(window, from_=0, to=100, length=200, variable=current_var, command=update_label)
current_var.set(100)
scale_bar.grid(row=0,column=0)

# Initialize scale's display label. Works without this, but it shows everything from the start
var_label=ttk.Label(window,text=f'{current_var.get()}'+'%',style="Info.TLabel")
var_label.grid(row=0,column=1)

window.mainloop()
```

I've tried `conf_label.grid_forget()` and then re-grid-ing it on the update function, but that didn't work. I've also tried making 2 separate labels (global/local) ones, although I may be thinking too linearly. I think I'm looking for a "screen refresh" but I don't know what that looks like. This also happens without the fore/background colors, or even without a relief altogether; removing the Style config and the style assignment from the label(s) will still leave a small part of `%` visible, once part if the current value is a double digit number, and 2 parts if it's a single digit number. A viable botch would be to force length by padding with whitespace, but this is a good learning opportunity. Thanks for reading!

Comment: The fix is to update the widget rather than creating a new widget each time. Research the `config` method.

Comment: `tkinter` doesn't remove old `Label` but it puts new `Label` above old `Label` - so you have two labels in one place. You would have to `grid_forget` old `Label` - and it needs to keep label in `global` variable. Or you should create `Label` only once and later replace text in existing `Label`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`tkinter` doesn't remove old `Label` but it puts new `Label` above old `Label` - so you have two labels in one place.

You could use `grid_forget()` or `destroy()` to remove old `Label`.

But this needs to keep `var_label` as `global` variable.

And this can make flickering widget. It shows gray background after removing old `Label` and before adding new `Label`.

```
def update_label(value):
    global var_label   # inform function that new label has to be assigned to global variable `var_label`, instead of local `var_label`

    current_var_levels = current_var.get()
    #current_var_levels = int(float(currvar))

    var_label.destroy()     # remove old label from screen and from memory
    #var_label.grid_forget()  # remove old label from screen but not from memory
    
    var_label = ttk.Label(window, text=f'{current_var_levels}%', style="Info.TLabel")
    var_label.grid(row=0, column=1)
```

Or you should create `Label` only once and later replace text in existing `Label`

```
def update_label(currvar):
    current_var_levels = current_var.get()
    #current_var_levels = int(float(currvar))

    var_label.config(text=f'{current_var_levels}%')  # replace text
    #var_label['text'] = f'{current_var_levels}%'    # replace text
```

---

Full working code which I used for tests:

```
import tkinter as tk       # `PEP8: `import *` is not preferred
import tkinter.ttk as ttk  # `PEP8: `import *` is not preferred

# --- functions ---  # PEP8: all functions before main code

def update_label_version_1(value):
    global var_label   # inform function that new label has to be assigned to global variable `var_label`, instead of local `var_label`

    current_var_levels = current_var.get()
    #current_var_levels = int(float(currvar))

    var_label.destroy()     # remove old label from screen and from memory
    #var_label.grid_forget()  # remove old label from screen but not from memory

    var_label = ttk.Label(window, text=f'{current_var_levels}%', style="Info.TLabel")
    var_label.grid(row=0, column=1)
    
def update_label_version_2(value):
    current_var_levels = current_var.get()
    #current_var_levels = int(float(value))
        
    var_label.config(text=f'{current_var_levels}%')  # replace text
    #var_label['text'] = f'{current_var_levels}%'    # replace text
    
# --- main ---

window = tk.Tk()

ttk.Style().configure("Info.TLabel", foreground="white", background="#1e2124", relief="sunken")

current_var = tk.IntVar()

#update_label = update_label_version_1   # test version 1
update_label = update_label_version_2   # test version 2

scale_bar = ttk.Scale(window, from_=0, to=100, length=200, variable=current_var, command=update_label)
current_var.set(100)
scale_bar.grid(row=0,column=0)

# Initialize scale's display label. Works without this, but it shows everything from the start
var_label = ttk.Label(window, text=f'{current_var.get()}%', style="Info.TLabel")
var_label.grid(row=0, column=1)

window.mainloop()
```

[PEP 8 -- Style Guide for Python Code](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/)

Comment: I can't upvote because my account is too new but thanks for taking the time, this works perfectly. However if I may ask something else, I think it's a little junky when the window resizes based on the number of digits. What would you do to avoid similar resizing?

Comment: first I was thinking about formatting text to 3 chars `f'{current_var_levels:3}%' and it adds `spaces` before `numbers` - but you use font in which `space` has smaller width. Using one of `monospace` font it could give expected effect. If you would add `zeros` instead of `spaces` `f'{current_var_levels:03}%' then it would keep size but `001%` doesn't look good. You may also use `Label(..., width=5)` to keep width. And it may need `Label(..., anchor='e')` to align text to right.

Comment: I'm not "married" to the font, so that sounds like a nice fix. Thanks a lot!